# unlimited number of buttons can be selected

Tags: jquery

I got a slight situation with my application. You can access my fiddle to see my application. But what happens is that if I open the grid and select an option (lets say option "5") it will display buttons "A" to "E". Now I have a text-box where you type in your Number of Answers (#NumberAnswersTxt), now if I type in the number 4 in the textbox, it will let the user select 4 buttons out of buttons "A" to "E". Anymore and an alert will appear saying beyond limit...

Now that works fine buts lets say I change the value in text-box to a number smaller than "4", lets say "2", then for some strange reason the user can select all buttons. Really if another buttons is attempted to be selected then it should pop up with the beyon alert limit but it doesn't.

So how can I get it so that if the value in the text-box is smaller than the original value, that it would not allow the user to click on unlimited buttons but instead pops up with the alert if the user attempts to select a button if the number of buttons selected is already passed the new value in the text-box?

The code is in Jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qWrKa/)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Towards the end of your js you need to replace

```
if (document.getElementById("numberAnswerTxt").value == currenttotal)
```

with

```
if (document.getElementById("numberAnswerTxt").value <= currenttotal)
```

As in

```
if (document.getElementById("numberAnswerTxt").value <= currenttotal) {
    alert('You are not allowed beyond the limit of the number of answers you require, deselect other button');
    return false;
}
```

That should solve your problem.